# Best way to continously update data in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone, continuous

I'm trying to create an application that will fetch data from a web API and display it, then continuously refresh the data every 5 seconds or so, but I don't know the best way to go about doing this.

My first thought was just a simple timer, doing something like what was done in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265715/is-there-a-timer-control-for-windows-phone-7), but I'm worried that I may mess it up and have the timer continue running in the background when it shouldn't be (like if the user leaves the page). Am I worried over something that isn't going to actually happen? Is this a good way to go about doing what I'm trying to do, or is there a more efficient/safe way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate outside app, timer will not continue, but when you navigate to another page inside app, timer will continue. You can prevent it this way:

```
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000); // 1000 Milliseconds
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Stop();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Start();
    }

    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(listBox1.Items.Count + 1); // for testing
    }

    private void PageTitle_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); // for testing
    }
```

Moreover, if you are just checking for data which most time is not changed, consider using [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).