# How to set timer in an event handler?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-7, eventhandler

Am currently building an app and I want the timer to start only when I click a particular button.

So is there anyway to start timer once a button is clicked? (I don't want the timer to start as soon as the page loads)

Comment: `Timer.Start` assuming you're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `Timer.Enabled = true`

Comment: thanks a lot :D you just pointed me in the right direction, so off i go!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265715/is-there-a-timer-control-for-windows-phone-7).

```
//Inside Page Load 
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500); // 500 Milliseconds
dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
```

Tick Event Handler for your timer

```
void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do Stuff here.
}
```

Now on your button click event handler you will do

```
dt.Start();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what type of classes or references should I include??! @Amar Palsapure

Comment: @F505 have you checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.100).aspx. You can check the .net framework also.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Enabled property of timer is false. Hence it will not start on load.
You can have a button click event which starts the timer on clicking it.

```
    private void btnStartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Add a Timer Tick event which confirms that the timer has started.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Timer Tick");
    }
```