# Timer event c# Crash

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, crash

I have a timer event as given below and I have got some suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892995/how-to-set-timer-in-an-event-handler) post. Could you suggest me what is wrong with this? I am getting the following crash:

Unable to cast object of type `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to type `System.Windows.Forms.Button`.
Any suggestions on where I am going wrong??

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ButtonTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(ButtonTimer_Tick);
    ButtonTimer.Interval = 100;
}

private void ButtonTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button CurrentButton = (Button)sender;

    string PressedButton = CurrentButton.Name;

    switch (PressedButton)
    {
        case "BoomUp":break;
    }
}

private void BoomUp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        //ButtonTimer.Enabled = true;
        ButtonTimer.Start();
    }

}

private void BoomUp_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ButtonTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem in `ButtomTime_Tick` method :

```
   Button CurrentButton = (Button)sender;
```

`sender` is not a `Button`, it's a `Timer`.

*So what you gonna do now ?*

You could add a private field in your class

```
private Button currentButton_;
```

and

```
private void BoomUp_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        currentButton_ = e.Button;//but I don't know if e.Button has a Name "BoomUp"
        //you can set the name manually if needed :
        currentButton_.Name = "BoomUp";

        //ButtonTimer.Enabled = true;
        ButtonTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

and

```
private void ButtonTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            switch (currentButton_.Name)
            {
                case "BoomUp":break;
             }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly where the crash is happening, but how do I get the current button? (If not from sender)

Comment: Ok got it. Slightly changed it when trying to get the name, but got the jist of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In `ButtonTimer_Tick` the sender is the timer, not a button. Hence you cast a timer into a button (1st line in that method).