# trigger event after X seconds

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, timer, visual-studio-2012, dispatchertimer

I am developing an app for windows phone. My question is how can I trigger an event after 2 seconds?

```
    Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    Dim input As String = txtinput.Text
    Dim last As Char = input(input.Length - 1)
    If last = "A" Then
        Dim final As String = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1) & "B"c
        txtinput.Text = final.

      'start timer here
      'trigger an event after 2 seconds

    ElseIf last = "B" Then
        Dim final As String = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1) & "C"c
        Dim tmr As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        txtinput.Text = final

      'start timer here
      'trigger an event after 2 seconds


    Else
        txtinput.Text = input + "A"
    End If

 End Sub
```

I am using Visual Basic as my language in developing this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What UI framework are you developing under? Does it not have a timer?

Comment: I am using visual basic as my language in developing this.

Comment: Yes, but are you using WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, etc...? For example, if you are using WinForms, there's a Timer in your toolbox you can drag onto your form. Then you just call `.Start()` on it and handle it's `Tick` event.

Comment: oh sorry, i am using windows phone application in visual studio express 2012..

Comment: see the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265715/is-there-a-timer-control-for-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare dispatcherTimer inside the class

```
Dim WithEvents dt As System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
```

then create instance of dispatcherTimer whereever you want, set time span

```
dt = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()
dt.Interval = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500) '' 500 Milliseconds
dt.Start()
```

and here is your handler

```
Private Sub dt_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles dt.Tick
    ' Do Stuff here.
End Sub
```

*converted code to VB from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265715/is-there-a-timer-control-for-windows-phone-7), though I have not tested it..it may work for you..

Comment: thank you so much. this code works the way what I want to happen. Thanks again.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I just don't know the environment because I have never programmed for phones in .Net, but what about:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That might cause the application to "freeze" for 2 seconds if it is done on the UI thread.