# Keep a Button control in the pressed state wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I keep a Button control in the pressed state in a windows phone 7 app using C#? I want to have many different buttons on the screen, but when I press any of them I want it to stay pressed. Any ideas?

Also, once it is in its pressed state, is there a way to "depress" it manually?

Thanks

Comment: not sure about `wp7`, but [`Timer`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3265715/1577396)?

Comment: Are you asking about only the visual state? or the actual button state itself? If it is the button itself, then if you keep it "pressed" would the button keep raising its clicked event?

Comment: @ryadavilli Yes I just mean the visual state.

Comment: @Mr_Green I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean you can go with Timers for this problem.. check the link I provided. I am not sure whether it will work in wp7 or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button properties are as follows:
  foreground: white
  background:black

Then in the pressing state its properties will be
  foreground: black
  background:white

If you change the properties of button in click event it can be seen as it is pressed.               And making the IsEnabled property of button prevents it from firing the events on buttons.