# WP7 How to write a function: binding data method will be called every 10s?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Could you show me the way or the idea how to execute biding data every 10s??

Let's see the code below:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       proxy.DanhSachPhongChoiCompleted += new 
          EventHandler<DanhSachPhongChoiCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_DanhSachPhongChoiCompleted);
       proxy.DanhSachPhongChoiAsync(); 
}  

void proxy_DanhSachPhongChoiCompleted(object sender, DanhSachPhongChoiCompletedEventArgs e)
{
      Room[] table = e.Result;
      listDSPhong.ItemsSource = e.Result;                
}
```

We can see: ater my page loaded, the binding data will execute ONLY ONE TIME. I need to call 2 methods below every 10s. How should I do? Thanks for teaching me!

```
proxy.DanhSachPhongChoiCompleted += new 
              EventHandler<DanhSachPhongChoiCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_DanhSachPhongChoiCompleted);
           proxy.DanhSachPhongChoiAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use e.g. DispatcherTimer class.

Here's the sample:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3266071/126995

You better start your timer in NavigatedTo, and kill it in NavigatedFrom.

P.S. I suspect there's a memory leak in your code. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133551/c-sharp-events-memory-leak).

Answer (score 0):

you can use Microsoft's reactive library

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

and do something like this :

```
public void callfunction() 
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = NewThreadScheduler.Default;
        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), new Action<Action<TimeSpan>>(myRepeatingFunction));
    }

private void myRepeatingFunction(Action<TimeSpan> action)
    {
        //process here
        action(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // five second interval
    }
```